# Raytracing seam-like rendering artifacts

Tags: graphics, intersection, raytracing

I have written a simple raytracer (the code is [here](https://github.com/bjourne/c-examples/blob/master/programs/raytrace/raytrace.c) but you don't have to debug it). It can render simple meshes:

[image: a cool tyrannosaurus]

It looks pretty cool, I think. There is no reflection in the raytracer and the pixels are shaded solely based on their interpolated normals. However, if you zoom up you see that there are rendering artifacts all over it:

[image]

My question is, what is causing these "dots" on the model? I know it must have something to do with the intersection test because here is the same model rendered with another intersection routine:

[image]

If you zoom, you can see that it has the same kind of rendering errors but they are much fewer. It is hard to debug this problem because it only manifests itself on high resolutions and high triangle count meshes that takes forever to render. Is this some kind of "known problem" with raytracing? If so, what can be done about it?

**Edit**: Appears my problem is precision related. I have a ray defined by the following origin and direction:

```
o = {11.998573303222656250000, 14.635927200317382812500, 9.681089401245117187500}
d = {-0.843012511730194091797, -0.274484694004058837891, -0.462588489055633544922}
```

It does not intersect the triangle defined by the following three vertices:

```
v0 = {-0.078872203826904296875, 10.742719650268554687500, 3.051664113998413085938}
v1 = {-0.071703910827636718750, 10.628479957580566406250, 3.061952114105224609375}
v2 = {-0.005743980407714843750, 10.743999481201171875000, 3.017672061920166015625}
```

My intersection test is correctly implemented which means that the non-hit must be due to the lack of precision in 32 bit floats. So then the question becomes what can be done about it?

Comment: so what direction does the normal point there, and did it come to an interseciton or what?

Comment: since this should be reproduceable, you should just concentrate on the area at and around one of these errors.

Comment: The pixels look black, not background-colored. If that is true and not an artifact of processing, then the error is likely in the shading part, and not in the part that calculates the intersection with the mesh. If you can, render the Z-buffer (depth information) into a separate buffer, and see if that is continuous. If it is not, then the error is in the intersection calculations. If it is continuous, but the pixel colors are off, the error is in the shading calculations.

Comment: just a silly guess (without looking at the code) but I suggest to check for out of range `acos` usage related to floating point rounding errors. I got similar artifacts in raytracers in past due to this (normalized vectors can have a bit different size than `1.0` making mess on range sensitive operations).

Comment: Take a look at Watertight Ray/Triangle Intersection - 
http://jcgt.org/published/0002/01/05/paper.pdf

Comment: @Vertexwahn: Is that problem what is causing the artifacts? The thing is that my raytracer is very ordinary so I'm  surprised that I can't find any discussion about this problem!

Comment: Your provided data seem to be incorrect -
 the ray does not intersect the triangle -
 see here: http://vertexwahn.de/Ether.Debug.png